# ffmpeg: UVC Interlaced Video

Tags: ffmpeg, video, deinterlace

I'm trying to combine an alternating fields interlaced video stream from an UVC video device. The device is an analog (CVBS) to digital converter that supports Interlaced video through usage of the FID flag in the UVC data headers. USB Video Class documentation explanation "One field per sample: Each sample contains only one field and the FID bit is used to indicate whether a given video sample contains a top field or a bottom field". Stream frame size is 720x288pix at 50fps and the output video should be "combed" and result a 720x576pix video at 25fps.

I tried weave and tinterlace filters but it works on random as ffmpeg seems to miss the data regarding the field polarity.

Could ffmpeg make use of this flag so that i can join two fields in one frame in correct order? If not ffmpeg that what other software could do that?